# Python HTTP request in thread amount limit

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there an upper limit for HTTP request + thread?
I was writing a program which I put HTTP connection and request into thread.
The http request to different server, but the thread will have exception that it cannot start thread.
The number of thread that shows exception I tested is about 670~680.
I am sure the problem goes on HTTP request, because when I remove the request I can start as many threads as I can.

```
Class A():
    for i in self.candidates:
        example = SearchingThread()
        self.devices.append(example)    
    for device in self.devices:
        device.get_running()

class SearchingThread(object):

    def __init__(self, interval=1):           
        self.interval = interval
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        self.thread.daemon = True  # Daemonize thread            
        self.sslconnect = http.client.HTTPSConnection
        self.connect = http.client.HTTPConnection
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        self.context.check_hostname = False
        self.context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    def get_running(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def run(self):            
        try:
            self.sslconnect = http.client.HTTPSConnection(self.host, context=self.context, timeout=timeout)
            self.sslconnect.request("GET", url, header)
            resp = self.sslconnect.getresponse()
```

Comment: Are you asking about max limit of threads or HTTP request as these two are different approaches.

Comment: please post the error and a simplified version of ur code

Comment: @PrashantShukla I'm asking HTTP request